# DPDK run testpmd failed. testpmd: No probed ethernet devices

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

I'm new to dpdk and using dpdk-stable-21.11.5 on Ubuntu 22.04. I have compiled and installed dpdk according to the official documentation. I bind two network devices to the vfio-pci driver. When I try to run dpdk-testpmd, it shows that it could not detect any Ethernet devices.

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:03:00.0 'Device 125c' drv=vfio-pci unused=igc,igb_uio,uio_pci_generic
0000:04:00.0 'Device 125c' drv=vfio-pci unused=igc,igb_uio,uio_pci_generic

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:02:00.0 'Device 125c' if=enp2s0 drv=igc unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:05:00.0 'Device 125c' if=enp5s0 drv=igc unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic 

No 'Baseband' devices detected
==============================

No 'Crypto' devices detected
============================

No 'DMA' devices detected
=========================

No 'Eventdev' devices detected
==============================

No 'Mempool' devices detected
=============================

No 'Compress' devices detected
==============================

No 'Misc (rawdev)' devices detected
===================================

No 'Regex' devices detected
===========================
```

```
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
testpmd: No probed ethernet devices
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
Done
No commandline core given, start packet forwarding
io packet forwarding - ports=0 - cores=0 - streams=0 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native

  io packet forwarding packets/burst=32
  nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=0
Press enter to exit

Telling cores to stop...
Waiting for lcores to finish...

  +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
  RX-packets: 0              RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 0
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 0
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Done.

Bye...
```

I have also tried the uio_pci_generic driver and igb_uio driver, and the results are still the same.

Comment: did you configure hugepages ? you can also try to run the skeleton from examples to check

Comment: @Hikaricat Please share the command you used to execute the testpmd program.